# Find common elements in a map of sequences - scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have something like this:

```
val myMap: Map[Int, Seq[Int]] = Map(1 -> (1, 2, 3), 2 -> (2, 3, 4), 3 -> (3, 4, 5), 4 -> (4, 5, 6))
```

I am trying to find a way to relate all the keys and their common elements in the sequence they are mapped to.

For example:

1 and 2 share (2, 3)

1 and 3 share (3)

2 and 3 share (3, 4)

2 and 4 share (4)

3 and 4 share (4, 5)

I suspect I need to use `intersect` but I am not sure how to go about the problem. I am brand new to scala and functional programming and need a little help getting started on this. I know there are probably easier ways to do this with spark, however, I am trying to stick just to scala.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want the results returned? Do you just want to print them to STDOUT?

```
myMap.keys.toList.combinations(2).foreach{ case List(a,b) => 
    println(s"$a,$b --> ${myMap(a) intersect myMap(b)}")
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful and put me on the right track. Unfortunately I did not take the scalability of my specific case into account. See my comment under @Tomer Shetah post. If you have any ideas please let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry if that came across as wrong. Very new to the forum, was not intending to do anything in an ill manner. Your answer does answer the question I asked, so I suppose I will mark it as answered and re-ask the question again in a more specific way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `flatMap` and `collect` to generate the shared values from every combination of the key pairs via `intersect`:

```
val myMap: Map[Int, List[Int]] = Map(
  1 -> List(1, 2, 3), 2 -> List(2, 3, 4), 3 -> List(3, 4, 5), 4 -> List(4, 5, 6)
)

val keys = myMap.keys.toList

keys.flatMap{ i => keys.collect{
    case j if j > i => (i, j, myMap(i) intersect myMap(j))
  }
}
// res1: List[(Int, Int, List[Int])] = List(
//   (1,2,List(2, 3)),
//   (1,3,List(3)),
//   (1,4,List()),
//   (2,3,List(3, 4)),
//   (2,4,List(4)),
//   (3,4,List(4, 5))
// )
```

The above is essentially the same as the following `for comprehension`:

```
for {
  i <- keys
  j <- keys
  if j > i
} yield (i, j, myMap(i) intersect myMap(j))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty similar to @jwvh solution, but with less lookups in the map, in case it is big:

```
val myMap: Map[Int, Seq[Int]] = Map(1 -> Seq(1, 2, 3), 2 -> Seq(2, 3, 4), 3 -> Seq(3, 4, 5), 4 -> Seq(4, 5, 6))
myMap.toList.combinations(2).foreach {
  case List((i1, s1), (i2, s2)) =>
    val ints = s1.intersect(s2)
    if (ints.nonEmpty) {
      println(s"$i1 and $i2 share (${ints.mkString(", ")})")
    }
  case _ => ???
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qGfXbAMpS7S0ghKRmKnetg).

Comment: All of these answers are exactly what I was looking for, thank you! However, in my specific case I am going through a map with over 10,000 keys that are mapped to Lists of different sizes. So naturally, it is somewhat inefficient. Any thoughts on a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: What is the range of sizes of those lists?

Comment: The sizes range from 1-40. Never will the size be less than one. I have re-asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66552691/efficiently-find-common-values-in-a-map-of-lists-scala) to specify more about the question.