# Efficiently find common values in a map of lists - scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I asked a similar question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540337/find-common-elements-in-a-map-of-sequences-scala/66546873#66546873). However, I misjudged the scale of my specific case. In my example I gave, there were only 4 keys in the map. I am actually dealing with over 10,000 keys and they are mapped to lists of different sizes. So the solution given was correct, but I am now looking for a way that will do this in a more efficient manner.

Say I have:

```
val myMap: Map[Int, List[Int]] = Map(
  1 -> List(1, 10, 12, 76, 105), 2 -> List(2, 5, 10), 3 -> List(10, 12, 76, 5), 4 -> List(2, 4, 5, 10), 
  ... -> List(...)
)
```

Imagine the `(...)` go on for over 10,000 keys. I want to return a List of Lists containing a pair of keys and their shared values if the size of the intersection of their respective lists is `>= 3`.

For example:

```
res0: List[(Int, Int, List[Int])] = List(
      (1, 3, List(10, 12, 76)),
      (2, 4, List(2, 5, 10)),
      (...),
      (...),
      )
```

I've been pretty stuck on this for a couple of days, so any help is genuinely appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would you consider O(n log n) to be efficient enough?

Comment: @BitTickler From my understanding O(log n) is most efficient to deal with large numbers of data in a set. However, I am not necessarily looking for the most efficient answer, just a much more efficient answer than my original post. So, I think O(n log n) would be efficient enough.

Comment: Can any of the input lists contain duplicates?

Comment: @BitTickler Nope. Every value in each input list is unique.

Comment: The key-pair `combinations` requirement is what elevates the computational load.  It would be rather straight forward if processing it on, say, `Apache Spark` (that leverages distributed computing power) were an option.

Comment: Ah I see. So this seems to be a rather tough problem to answer when faced with a single desktop's computing power.

Comment: Even if there are 10s of thousands of values, we are probably talking about milliseconds of computing time. So, unless you need that within some small hard realtime time spans, even modern smartphones should be fast enough. (If you sort all lists (O(N logN) and then just iterate (O(N)), you should have a quite performant implementation. I know nothing about scala, but it runs on jvm, which is reasonably fast (but even in slow motion computing (python), it should not take more than a few 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

If space is not the concern then the problem can be solved in the O(N) where N is the number of elements in the list.

Algorithm:

- Create a reverse lookup map out from the input map. Here reverse lookup maps the list element to the key (Id).
- For each input map key

  - Create a temp map
  - Iterate over the list and look for value (Id) in the reverse lookup. Count the number of occurred for the fetched id.
  - All key which occurred equal or more than 3 times is the desired pair.

Code

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object Application extends App {

  val inputMap = Map(
    1 -> List(1, 2, 3, 4),
    2 -> List(2, 3, 4, 5),
    3 -> List(3, 5, 6, 7),
    4 -> List(1, 2, 3, 6, 7))
  
/*
  Expected pairs

  |  pair | common elements |
  ---------------------------
  (1, 2) -> 2, 3, 4
  (1, 4) -> 2, 3, 4
  (2, 1) -> 2, 3, 4
  (3, 4) -> 3, 5, 6
  (4, 1) -> 1, 2, 3
  (4, 3) -> 3, 5, 6
   */

  val reverseMap = mutable.Map[Int, ArrayBuffer[Int]]()

  inputMap.foreach {
    case (id, list) => list.foreach(
      o => if (reverseMap.contains(o)) reverseMap(o).append(id) else reverseMap.put(o, ArrayBuffer(id)))
  }

  val result = inputMap.map {
    case (id, list) =>
      val m = mutable.Map[Int, Int]()
      list.foreach(o =>
        reverseMap(o).foreach(k => if (m.contains(k)) m.update(k, m(k)+1) else m.put(k, 1)))
      val res = m.toList.filter(o => o._2 >= 3 && o._1 != id).map(o => (id, o._1))
      res
  }.flatten

  println(result)
}
```

Comment: This indeed gets the job done. I am trying to figure this out in a functional manner, though. I'm still a newbie to functional programming and scala in general, but wouldn't using mutable maps not be considered functional?

Comment: Yeah mutation makes it non functional code. I'll soon update the answer with immutable code.

Comment: If the range of the integers in the lists is limited to some known, small range (e.g. 16 bit values), you can optimize this further by not using a map but a simple, sufficiently sized array.

Comment: In order to translate this idea to pure functional and yet performant code, you will need to rely on [persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure). If scala has the ambition to support pure functional programming, it should offer them in its standard library.